# Object attribute undefined but it exists

Tags: javascript

I have just seen a strangest error ever.

so I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
    <input id="registration-firstname" type="text" required>
    <label>First name</label>
</div>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
    <input id="registration-last-name" type="text" required>
    <label>Last name</label>
</div>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
    <input id="registration-email" type="email" required>
    <label>Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="mui-select">
    <select id="registration-role">
        <option>user</option>
        <option>courier</option>
    </select>
    <label>Role</label>
</div>
```

**javascript**:

```
var elements = {
        messages : {
            ...non relevant object...
        },
        forms : {
            registration : {
                "firstname" :  document.getElementById('registration-firstname'),
                "lastname " :  document.getElementById('registration-last-name'),
                "email" :  document.getElementById('registration-email'),
                "role" :  document.getElementById('registration-role')
            }
        }
}
```

**problem**

If I do this:

console.log(elements.form.registration);

It will print:

```
Object { firstname: <input#registration-firstname>, lastname : <input#registration-last-name>, email: <input#registration-email>, role: <select#registration-role>, password: <input#registration-password> }
```

So it is clear that lastname attribute exists. But if I do this

```
console.log(elements.forms.registration.lastname)
```

it will print:

```
undefined
```

I have triple checked whether the lastname attribute exists I have even tried to

```
console.log(Object.keys(elements.forms.registration))
```

and that printed

```
Array [ "firstname", "lastname ", "email", "role", "password" ]
```

What makes things even more strange - problem does not happen for any other attribute in given object.

Comment: Did you try `elements.forms.registration['lastname']` ?

Comment: Is there any other javascript being executed?

Comment: I found error - I had a bloody whitespace :(

Comment: You have a space after "lastname ". Change it to "lastname".

Comment: When do you print this lastname in your console? Your element (#registration-last-name) might not be ready yet to be queried  via dom.

Comment: @Blauharley that was the first thing I had checked. But whitespace made mess for me

Comment: This question should be closed as "typo". Instead of that, an answer posted 2 minutes after mine and OP's comments, which clearly showed it was a simple typo, has 4 upvotes... Let's call a day.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It should be closed I agree

Comment: To make things worse, the other answer, which can make future readers think that in JS there is difference in writting an object's property name with or without quotes - when there is **no difference** - has also 4 upvotes. Clearly, democracy is broken since 2016.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado don't be so harsh. Chill a bit, my problem is solved with the help of you guys, thank you all so much

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I just updated my answer to satisfy your hesitate

Comment: I don't understand such flame - everyone makes silly mistakes once in a while. If an error is silly does that mean that one has no right to ask question here? Come on guys such things happen

Comment: @Rouz I'm not being harsh, I'm very cool right now. The thing is: S.O. is a knowledge database, not a personal debugging service. In that sense, as your question was clearly a typo (and I'm happy you solved it) since both your and my comment were posted, the answers were unnecessary. I believe you're not understanding this. Anyway, I'm the wrong one here, have you all a great day.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I disagree with you on this point. it is a question and answer website that turned out to become a knowledge database.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado http://stackoverflow.com/company/about  "Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems " <- a typo  **is** a coding problem. It is a stupid problem I agree but it still is a problem.

Comment: @Rouz Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "*Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: [...] Questions about a problem [...] that was caused by a simple typographical error*". Your question is off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: @Oriol mate, I had already marked this for closing once I found out that this was the case. As you can see above I agreed on that with Geraldo. No one challenged that. I just say that there is no need to go to full dicks-out mode over that... Chill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. You have extra trailing whitespace in

```
//       ↓
"lastname "
```

Comment: yep that was the problem. I watched for 3 hours in code before posting it here, and then I saw it... Silly me...

Answer (score 1):

In spite of the fact that there is no difference in defining objects with `""` quotes or not, Change this

```
registration : {
                "firstname" :  document.getElementById('registration-firstname'),
                "lastname " :  document.getElementById('registration-last-name'),
                "email" :  document.getElementById('registration-email'),
                "role" :  document.getElementById('registration-role')
            }
```

to

```
registration : {
                firstname :  document.getElementById('registration-firstname'),
                lastname :  document.getElementById('registration-last-name'),
                email :  document.getElementById('registration-email'),
                role :  document.getElementById('registration-role')
            }
```

Comment: If you dont have "First Name" key in your object so why use pharantesis ?

Comment: @SalihŞenolÇakarcı I +1 your answer because I managed to see my whitespace like that

Comment: thanks, you made mistake accidentially and my answer solves it accidentially too :)